# Adding words that curve to an svg document

Tags: text, svg, path

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlnslink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<path id="path1" d="M25, 100 C10,10 175,10 175,100" />
</defs>
<text font-size="19.5" fill="blue">
<textPath xlink:href="#path1">Hello text-on-a-path world!</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

I tried using this code I got from the internet but the error: "line 7 at column 23:       Namespace prefix xlink for href on textPath is not defined" came up on my browser. Actually the part I got from the internet is didn't include my opening and closing svg tags, just what's inside. I added the code beginning with xmlns because I thought I saw somewhere that was the way to define the namespace prefix.

Here's the code I used that worked:

```
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"  />

<text fill="red" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15" word-spacing="4" letter-

spacing="2" padding-left="30px">
<textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
  -----------------Support Your Local Devil 

Worshipper-------------------------------
</textPath>
</text>
```

Comment: I found the answer. the way I fixed it is by using this code: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <path id="MyPath"
          d=
           "M 200 9 a 111 111 0 1 0 0.00001 0
              " />
  </defs>
 
  <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"  />
 
  <text fill="red" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15" word-spacing="4" letter-

spacing="2" padding-left="30px">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      -----------------Support Your Local Devil 

Worshipper-------------------------------
    </textPath>
   </text>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a colon between xmlns and xlink

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:link="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```